# What is the best way to copy a list of files with these variable filenames using Path.Combine

Tags: c#, foreach, path, copy

I have source directories c:\source\yyyy-MM-dd where `yyyy-MM-dd` represents a range of dates, and a destination directory e:\destination. I need to look for multiple filenames in each date directory in that range of dates and only copy (`filenameA*.*`, `filenameB*.*`, `filenameC*.*`). I then need to create the date directories from the range of dates and copy the associated files found into their respective directories.

I'm using two datetimepickers to get the range of dates. I have that foreach logic working fine. I'm only struggling with the best way to use Path.Combine to create the destination folders and copy each of the files. I think I'm doing unnecessary work in my existing code, and I keep confusing myself:

```
    private async void ProcessFiles()
    {
        // create a list of topics
        var topics = topicsBox.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();

        // create a list of source directories based on date range
        var directories = new List<string>();
        var folders = new List<string>();
        for (DateTime date = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
            date.Date <= dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
            date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            var dateDir = _tracePath + @"\" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + @"\";
            directories.Add(dateDir);
            folders.Add(@"\" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + @"\");
        }

        // create a list of source files to copy and destination
        foreach (var path in directories)
        {
            var path1 = path;
            try
            {
                foreach (var files2 in folders)
                {
                    var destPath = textBox1.Text + @"\" + textBox4.Text + files2;

                    foreach (var files in topics)
                    {
                        if (!Directory.Exists(path1))
                        {
                            toolStripStatusLabel1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ("Could not find \"" + path1 +
                                                          "\" Check start and end date.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (
                                string sourcePath in
                                    Directory.EnumerateFiles(path1, files + "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
                            {

                                var filename = Path.GetFileName(sourcePath); // get each filename in source directory
                                var fullDestPath = Path.Combine(destPath, filename); // create the destination folder name

                                Directory.CreateDirectory(sourcePath.Replace(sourcePath, destPath)); // create the destination folder

                                // copy the files to the temp folder asynchronously
                                using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(sourcePath, FileMode.Open))
                                {
                                    using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(fullDestPath))
                                    {
                                        xferBtn.Enabled = false;

                                        toolStripStatusLabel1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                                        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Copying " + sourcePath;

                                        await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);

                                        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Copying complete!";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To start, it may be easier to break things apart into separate methods to keep track of tasks. I find this to be easier when doing multiple tasks in one method. I just created a simple test to copy files from a source to destination. This won't match your logic, but it may lead you in the right direction. When you enumerate over files, you get an IEnumerable object to work with. You can use that to just iterate over your file paths. Also, you have a DirectoryInfo object you can use to check for directory creation before copying. I also did not follow your logic with source/destination stream, but instead just used the System.File.IO.Copy method that show how Path.Combine works. This is an easy way to combine say a path to a directory and a file without concatenation. Its basically a string.Format("{0}", somthingToAppend).

```
private void BtnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // create a list of source directories based on date range
  List<string> sourceDirectories = new List<string>();
  List<string> destDirectories = new List<string>();
  sourceDirectories.Add("C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\Dir1");
  sourceDirectories.Add("C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\Dir2");
  destDirectories.Add("C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\Dest1");
  destDirectories.Add("C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\Dest2");

  // create a list of source files to copy and destination
  foreach (var path in sourceDirectories)
  {
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
      //Error message here if path does not exist or continue with the next path
      continue;
    }

    try
    {
      IEnumerable<string> paths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
      DirectoryInfo destPathInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirectories[0]); // create the destination folder

      if (destPathInfo.Exists)
      {
        foreach (var p in paths)
        {
          string destination = System.IO.Path.Combine(destDirectories[0], System.IO.Path.GetFileName(p));
          System.IO.File.Copy(p, destination);
        }

        destDirectories.RemoveAt(0);
      }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
  }
}
```